# Print a fragment SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to print a fragment using `window.print()` but not getting the expected output.
I am using below code :

```
var $domTarget = oTarget.mAggregations.content["0"].mAggregations.content["0"]                           .mAggregations.pages["0"].mAggregations.content["0"].$()[0];                                 
var sTargetContent = $domTarget.innerHTML;
var sOriginalContent = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = sTargetContent;
window.print();
```

I am getting first half of fragment printed but not second half.

Comment: The question you need to put in the first place is why are you manipulating the DOM directly? 
The UI5 API allows you to bypass that altogether and since you are using UI5 you might as well use the API.

Comment: i have my fragment embedded inside other view and fragment so directly using UI5 api i am not getting desired output. So i am using DOM.

Comment: I don't understand that. The whole point of a fragment is to be in its own file so you can re-use it. Maybe put the code there so we can understand the context better.

Comment: @greven I have a fragment i want to print it using a button the function i am using right now on click of button is:  What different can i do?

Comment: var oTarget = this.getView();                                                                     var $domTarget = oTarget.mAggregations.content["0"].mAggregations.content["0"]                           .mAggregations.pages["0"].mAggregations.content["0"].$()[0];                                 
var sTargetContent = $domTarget.innerHTML;
var sOriginalContent = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = sTargetContent;
window.print();